# assigning the result of a jsp confirm box to a php variable

Tags: php, javascript

```
//this is in php.
function msgbox($msg, $type)
    {
    if ($type == "alert")
        {
        // Simple alert window
        ?> <script language="JavaScript"> alert("<? echo $msg; ?>"); </script> <?
        }
    elseif ($type == "confirm")
        {
        // Enter Confirm Code Here and assign the $result variable for use
        // Should include "OK" and "Cancel" buttons.
        ?>
           <script language="JavaScript">
           if (confirm("<? echo $msg; ?>"))
                {
                <? $result == "ok"; ?>
                }
           else
                {
                <? $result == "cancel"; ?>
                }
           </script>
        <?
        }
    }



if ($page_title->exists())

{msgbox("page exists,do you want to delete", "confirm");

}
if ($result == "ok")

 //code..
```

The problem is that `$result` is not reading the value from the confirm box i think because the if clause is not being executed and the program flow is going where it would go without the if clause.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122529/assigning-the-result-of-a-javascript-confirm-box-to-a-php-variable

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand when is your PHP and JavaScript code executed. First the server runs your PHP code. This generates HTML output, that gets passed to your browser and the browser executes the JavaScript code. This means that when you run `confirm()` in JavaScript, your PHP code is already finished (and probably serving another request).

You will need to rethink the user interaction.

(Btw, JSP means Java Servlet Pages, not JavaScript)